# graphing library for C#

Tags: c#, database, controls

I'm looking for an open source or cheap way to graph/chart data. I searched here and found some on github and codeplex, but there wern't any screen shots. There seemed to be a good one for Silverlight, but I got caught in a 'need to update - already up to date' loop. Recommendations? Thanks.

edit: Unfortunately i'm using Visual C# 2010 Express. I don't think it's available for the express versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about zedgraph?

[klick me](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/samples.html)

i used that for x-y-graphs, but it is able to do alot more :)

Comment: Looks like this will work. But the http://zedgraph.org site appears to be down. Would you happen to have a help document, or a list of classes? Thanks.

Comment: there is a documentation at sourceforge: [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/files/zedgraph%20documentation/) a "small" chm file, i think it contains everything you need :)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say which version of VS you're using, but [Chart Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456632.aspx) is built in for VS2010+.

Comment: It's available for earlier versions too: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14422  Either works on Express.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a Silverlight library, you can find it in [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com). For WPF, it is included in the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com). Otherwise, as mentioned in another answer, for Windows Forms the charting library is included in the standard framework for .NET 4.